# How to select an individual cell in a SWT Tree with a TreeCursor

Tags: java, eclipse, swt

First I was surprised that `TreeCursor.setSelection(TreeItem row, int column)` didn't select anything. Then I looked into the source of this method and found that they call `Tree.indexOf()`. Of course it won't find the tree item if it isn't direct child of the tree.
Don't I understand something about the usage of this class? Is it possible to select a tree item which is not direct child of the tree? I hardly believe that the selection functionality is so limited. I mean a tree is a tree and has usually one root and deep hierarchy...

```
import org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.viewers.model.TreeCursor;
import org.eclipse.swt.SWT;
import org.eclipse.swt.layout.FillLayout;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Tree;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TreeColumn;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TreeItem;

public class Test {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Display display = new Display();
        Shell shell = new Shell(display);
        shell.setLayout(new FillLayout());

        Tree tree = new Tree(shell, SWT.V_SCROLL | SWT.H_SCROLL | SWT.BORDER | SWT.SINGLE | SWT.FULL_SELECTION);

        tree.setHeaderVisible(true);
        TreeColumn column1 = new TreeColumn(tree, SWT.LEFT);
        column1.setText("Column 1");
        column1.setWidth(200);
        TreeColumn column2 = new TreeColumn(tree, SWT.CENTER);
        column2.setText("Column 2");
        column2.setWidth(200);
        TreeColumn column3 = new TreeColumn(tree, SWT.RIGHT);
        column3.setText("Column 3");
        column3.setWidth(200);
        TreeColumn column4 = new TreeColumn(tree, SWT.RIGHT);
        column4.setText("Column 4");
        column4.setWidth(200);

        TreeItem root = new TreeItem(tree, SWT.NONE);
        root.setText(new String[] { "root", "a1", "b1", "c1" });

        TreeItem rootChild1 = new TreeItem(root, SWT.NONE);
        rootChild1.setText(new String[] { "rootChild1", "a2", "b2", "c2" });

        TreeItem rootChild2 = new TreeItem(root, SWT.NONE);
        rootChild2.setText(new String[] { "rootChild2", "a2", "b2", "c2" });

        TreeCursor cursor = new TreeCursor(tree, SWT.NONE);
//      cursor.setSelection(root, 2);
        cursor.setSelection(rootChild1, 2);

        shell.open();
        while (!shell.isDisposed()) {
            if (!display.readAndDispatch()) {
                display.sleep();
            }
        }
        display.dispose();
    }
}
```

If you uncomment the line 'cursor.setSelection(root, 2);' you will see that the selection works as expected.

Comment: What do you mean with _"select a tree item which is not direct child of the tree"_? How can the item not be a child of the tree? Do you mean direct child of the root?

Comment: With the "direct child of the tree" I meant an item which is created with new TreeItem(tree, SWT.NONE); With this constructor it would be possible to create many "roots" which is wrong because a tree can have only one root. That's why I didn't use this word.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure I understand your problem, but this code works for me and selects a `TreeItem` that is not a direct child of the root:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Display display = Display.getDefault();
    final Shell shell = new Shell(display);
    shell.setText("StackOverflow");
    shell.setLayout(new FillLayout());

    Tree tree = new Tree(shell, SWT.NONE);

    TreeItem parent = new TreeItem(tree, SWT.NONE);
    parent.setText("root");

    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        TreeItem child = new TreeItem(parent, SWT.NONE);
        child.setText("child " + i);

        parent = child;
    }

    tree.setSelection(parent);

    shell.pack();
    shell.open();
    while (!shell.isDisposed())
    {
        if (!display.readAndDispatch())
            display.sleep();
    }
    display.dispose();
}
```

It looks like this when running:

[image]

Comment: I want to use TreeCursor.setSelection(TreeItem row, int column) to select the column too.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found the solution. I switched from `org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.viewers.model.TreeCursor` to `org.eclipse.swt.custom.TreeCursor` (which exists since Eclipse 3.8) and the issue was resolved.